# Generate the columns dynamically based on the date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table Metric Data

```
Metric ID         Metric Date             Metric Result       Metric Calculation Color
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001              2004-04-01                 1                   GREEN
002              2004-04-01                 0                   RED
001              2004-05-01                 1                   GREEN
002              2004-05-01                 5                   YELLOW
003              2004-05-01                 2                   GREEN
```

I want result-set something like

```
Metric ID        April Result           April Calc Color    May Result   May Calc Color
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001               1                       GREEN                1          RED
002               0                       RED                  5          YELLOW
003                                                            2          GREEN
```

I have used pivot table concept but it is giving me the duplicate results like

```
Metric ID        April Result           April Calc Color    May Result   May Calc Color
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001               1                       GREEN                NULL       NULL
001               NULL                    NULL                 1          RED
002               0                       RED                  NULL       NULL
002               NULL                    NULL                 5          YELLOW
003                                                            2          GREEN
```

This is the query i used

```
;With CTE AS
( 
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT C.METRIC_ID,RESULT,COLOR FROM METRICDATA ) Q PIVOT (MAX(RESULT) FOR [RESULT] IN ([April],[May]) )Pv ) PIVOT (MAX(COLOR) FOR [RESULT] IN ([April],[May]) )Pv1 )
```

The metric result and calculation color column should be generated based on date limit provided by the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ;With CTE
AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  C.METRIC_ID,RESULT,COLOR
    FROM   METRICDATA
    ) Q
       PIVOT
            (MAX(RESULT)
             FOR [RESULT]
             IN ([April],[May])
             )Pv
 )       PIVOT
            (MAX(COLOR)
             FOR [RESULT]
             IN ([April],[May])
             )Pv1
 )

Comment: If you can get that result why don't you just aggregate it a final time? Like SELECT Metric_ID, MAX(April_Result) AS April_Result, MAX(April_Calc_Color) AS April_Calc_Color, MAX(May_Result) AS May_Result, MAX(May_Calc_Color) AS May_Calc_Color FROM MyPivot GROUP BY Metric_ID

Comment: I dont know the exact month range it should be passed as parameter and if I am using aggregate it is taking the value of latest month alone in the result set and returning  NULL as a value for all the other months.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of pivot

```
Select metricId,
Case when datepart(Metric_Date)=4 then Metric_Result else o end 'April Result',
Case when datepart(Metric_Date)=4 then Metric_Color else NULL end 'April Calc Color',
Case when datepart(Metric_Date)=5 then Metric_Result else o end 'MayResult',
Case when datepart(Metric_Date)=5 then Metric_Color else NULL end 'May Calc Color'
from Metric
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fun.  SQLFiddle doesn't like my code (I doesn't seem to like variables much) but this works on my local box.  Here's the schema to test:

```
CREATE TABLE METRICDATA
    ([Metric_ID] varchar(3), [Date] date, [Result] int, [Color] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO METRICDATA
    ([Metric_ID], [Date], [Result], [Color])
VALUES
    ('001', '2004-04-01', 1, 'GREEN'),
    ('002', '2004-04-01', 0, 'RED'),
    ('001', '2004-05-01', 1, 'GREEN'),
    ('002', '2004-05-01', 5, 'YELLOW'),
    ('003', '2004-05-01', 2, 'GREEN')
;
```

And here's the code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE,
        @EndDate AS DATE,
        @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @StartDate = '20040401';
SET @EndDate = '20040501';

WITH cteWithMonths
AS
(
    SELECT      Metric_ID,
                DATENAME(MONTH, Date) AS MonthName,
                DATEPART(M, Date) AS Month,
                MAX(DATEPART(M, Date)) OVER () AS MaxMonth,
                Color
    FROM
                METRICDATA
    WHERE
                Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    GROUP BY
                Metric_ID,
                DATENAME(MONTH, Date),
                DATEPART(M, Date),
                Color
),
cteSQLFieldList
AS
(
    SELECT      0 AS LineNum, 'SELECT DISTINCT m.Metric_ID,' AS SQL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      DISTINCT
                MONTH,
                CASE 
                    WHEN Month < MaxMonth THEN MonthName + '.' + MonthName + '_Result, ' + MonthName + '.' + MonthName + '_Calc_Color,'
                    ELSE MonthName + '.' + MonthName + '_Result, ' + MonthName + '.' + MonthName + '_Calc_Color'
                END
    FROM        cteWithMonths
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      13,
                'FROM METRICDATA m'
),
cteSQLJoinList
AS
(
    SELECT      DISTINCT
                MONTH + 13 AS LineNum,
                'LEFT JOIN (SELECT Metric_ID, SUM(RESULT) AS ' + MonthName + '_Result, Color AS ' + MonthName + '_Calc_Color FROM METRICDATA WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, Date) = ''' + MonthName + ''' GROUP BY Metric_ID, Color) ' + MonthName +' ON m.Metric_ID = ' + MonthName + '.Metric_ID' AS SQL
    FROM        cteWithMonths
),
cteSQLOrderByList
AS
(
    SELECT      26 AS LineNum,
                'ORDER BY m.Metric_ID' AS SQL
),
cteSQL_ALL
AS
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM        cteSQLFieldList
    UNION
    SELECT      *
    FROM        cteSQLJoinList
    UNION
    SELECT      *
    FROM        cteSQLOrderByList
)

SELECT      @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' ', '') + SQL
FROM        cteSQL_ALL
ORDER BY    LineNum;

EXEC(@SQL);
```

I didn't want to play with your PIVOT solution, to be honest.  It looked to complicated to build dynamically.  I opted instead for aggregations for each Metric_ID in dervied tables and then JOIN all of them together.  I produce the necessary dynamic SQL then execute it.